# Internet Sharing on macOS 13.4.1 Ventura only works intermittently (requires reboot to resolve)

Tags: macos, ventura, internet-sharing

I have a MacBook Air M1 (2020). It is running macOS Ventura 13.4.1. It is connected Internet via Ethernet.

I am using the Internet Sharing feature in macOS. I share it to the WiFi.

[image]

The normal behaviour is that when I activate Internet Sharing the system till create a local WiFi network and the WiFi icon changes to show that.

[image: WiFi icon]

At this point I can connect other devices to the macOS WiFi network, as expected.

The issue is that after disabling the WiFi on the Mac (in order to turn it off), or putting the Mac to sleep, I can't turn on the Internet Sharing again. Or sometimes I can one or two more times, but eventually it stops working. Turning on Internet Sharing will not longer turn on a local WiFi network.

On some attempts it would work if I disabled WiFi and then turn on Internet Sharing, and it will prompt me to allow the WiFi to be turned on (when I activate Internet Sharing), and it might work one more time. But on repeated attempts, most of the time that also doesn't occur. It seems very inconsistent.

*The only solution I have found is to restart the Mac*. But then all of the above will play out again.

**I have two question:**

1. Any thoughts on why macOS is doing this? I suspect it's buggy.
2. Is there any way to completely refresh the network system in the same way a system restart does, but without restarting the system? (via some wizards in Terminal)

I found [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/450758/24991) describing a similar issue on macOS 13.0.1. But the suggested answer was something I already tried (as described above), and it only works randomly, and not more than once or twice.

### Adapter Info

The adapter has the following `ifconfig` info:

```
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 48:65:ee:14:d4:18
    inet6 fe80::90:5f18:be82:b8ec%en5 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xa
    inet6 2605:e000:efc0:b0:c4c:57ba:966a:20c7 prefixlen 128 dynamic
    inet 76.173.84.226 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 76.173.85.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

Comment: Could you include in your OQ the return of `ifconfig enxxx` where `enxxx` is the name of your "USB ETH SATECHI"? You can get this mapping from MacOS fancy names to Unix physical interface names with the command `networksetup -listallhardwareports`.

Comment: From your Mac, can you `ping` your Internet router?

Comment: Thanks Dan. There's no issue pinging the router. The `ifconfig` info I've now added to my question above. Interestingly, the output of `networksetup -listallhardwareresports` displayed the original fancy name of the adapter (`USB 10/100/1000 LAN`), as opposed to the one I gave it.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a combination of things.  I’d start with taking a look at your routing table (`netstat -rn`) and see what the values are both when working and when it fails.  It could be as simple as bad routing table data, something hosing up ip forwarding, the NAT firewall, etc.

Comment: @Allan: good investigation start. I think the problem might come from the fact that there might be many interfaces which are on ( `ifconfig -a | grep UP` ) and switched to automatically when Wi-Fi is turned off.

Comment: [Those interfaces on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332194/119271) are supposed to be up and are not related to your IP routing table.

Comment: Could you try this method for some time: `[↵]`
- before putting your Mac to sleep or turning Wi-Fi off, first turn Internet Sharing on,`[↵]`
- on exit from sleep, or on next need, just start Internet Sharing on and let it start the Wi-Fi on its own?